# Redirect to reload current page view after form POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In a simple blog application, when a user comments on a post, what's the recommended way to redirect to that same variable route or permalink to display the new comment (in django)?

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^comments/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)$', views.comments, name="thread"),
    url(r'^post/comment/$', views.post_comment, name="post_comment"),
]
```

In the view, I can get the url with `request.get_full_path()`, but I assume rather than stripping off `post_id` there's a better way to pass it to the redirect. Example view (but not right):

```
def post_comment(request):

   author = User.objects.get(user=request.user)
   new_comment = request.POST.get('commentContent', None)
   parent_object = None
   comment = Comment.create(author=author,
                            new_comment=new_comment,
                            parent=parent_object)

   comment.save()
   return redirect('/comments/{}'.format(comment.post.id))
```

submitting the comment form will log:

```
[28/Feb/2017 05:21:33] "POST /post/comment/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[28/Feb/2017 05:21:33] "GET /comments/{{post_id}} HTTP/1.1" 200 44831
```

and the form posts correctly, but the page won't reload/redirect

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with reverse:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# at the end of your view
redirect_to = reverse('blog:thread', kwargs={'post_id': post.id})
return redirect(redirect_to)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. It does not reload the page, i.e., does not rerun the get method of the view (i am using class-based view).

Comment: will be nice if you will create a new question with the code which is not working.